# Sigma.js exporter and filters

Tags: javascript, gephi, sigma.js

I have used Gephi and the Sigma exporter plugin to create a network graph. However, there are several extra features I want to add. I am a JavaScript and jQuery newbie, so the answer probably lies there.

As can be seen [here](http://www.lancaster.ac.uk/sci-tech/test/WorkSpace/), I have added in the option for a tick box to hide universities on the nodes, which have a boolean for a University attribute.

I would like to write something along the lines of

```
  if(checkbox){
  nodewithAttribute(TRUE).hide();
  }
```

But I have no idea how to check the node attributes and their values.